# ios, navigationbar is overlapped with its content view

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I'm presenting a viewcontroller like below, and the presented view controller's content overlaps the navigationbar of its own.

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = 
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];

//now present this navigation controller modally 
[self presentViewController:navigationController
                   animated:YES
                   completion:^{

                        }];
```

I can probably fix it by adjusting the contentView's frame origin/size but, is there an easier way?

self.webview is the contentview, and I used to have the following code to fit the webview to the entire screen - navigationbar - statusbar. (which worked well when I just `pushedViewController`)

```
self.webview.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
[self.view addSubview:self.webview];
self.webview.frame = self.webview.superview.bounds;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @AsifAsif: I added them, above is the current buggy image, 2nd is the desired image.

Comment: try adding these lines in `viewDidLoad`: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`

Comment: @AsifAsif:  mysterious.. but wow it worked! .. can you move your comment to an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: I actually saw that solution in one of SO answers, but didn't believe it would affect my case. because my navigation bar is already transcluent..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add following lines in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES; 
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question. The accepted answer may still work, but is really only correct for iOS 7 through 9. As of iOS 10 [the docs say this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621515-edgesforextendedlayout#discussion):

> Instead of this property, use the safe area of your view to determine which parts of your interface are occluded by other content. For more information, see the safeAreaLayoutGuide and safeAreaInsets properties of UIView.